# Indicator function

Tags: math-mode, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How do you represent Indicator function in LaTeX?

I would like to use something like `\mathbb` or `\mathcal`  on the "1" character; is it possible?

Comment: Page 68 in the "Comprehensive List of LaTeX Symbols"

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside

Comment: @egreg Does Page 68 in the "Comprehensive List of LaTeX Symbols" mean "Table 134: MnSymbol Triangle Relations", I didn't find Indicator function symbol in that page, actually I didn't find anything about Indicator function through whole [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: @JJJohn It's now table 307, page 119 in the much expanded list. See the “blackboard bold fonts”.

Comment: @egreg I got it. Thank you so much!