# Piecewise-defined functions

Tags: math-mode, equations, cases

I'm trying to write these four piecewise-defined functions.

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
\begin{equation}
 \theta = \begin{cases}
  \theta r + Se \left( \theta s - \theta r \right)  & Hp < 0 \\
  \theta s                                                        & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 Se =  \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{[1 + |\alpha Hp|^n]^m}  & Hp < 0 \\
  1                                               & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 C_m = \begin{cases}
  \frac{\alpha m}{1 - m} \left( \theta s - \theta r \right) Se^{\frac{1}{m}} [1 - Se^{\frac{1}{m}} ]^m & Hp < 0 \\
  0                                                                                                                                                & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 K_r = \begin{cases}
  Se^ l [1-[1- Se^{\frac{1}{m}}]^m] ^2 & Hp < 0 \\
  1                                                       & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases}\\
\end{equation}
```

And I got this result:[image]

How is it possible to separate these four piecewise-defined functions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a function (piecewise) with bracket outside?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside)

Comment: You just need a single `&`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Thanks for including most of the required code. But, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 8):

Only use one ampersand, `&`.

See page 68 in lshort: https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf

Example:

```
\begin{equation*}
    |x| = \begin{cases}
              -x & \text{if } x < 0,\\
               0 & \text{if } x = 0,\\
               x & \text{if } x > 0.
          \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: I tend to prefer `cases*` which gives you the second cell in text mode so this line would be ``-x & if $x < 0$,\\``. BTW, what font is that?

Comment: Yes, the starred version is useful. It's the Arev font: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/arev/

Answer (score 4):

Besides the use of `cases` as per Tommy L's answer, you could also:

1. Use an `align` environment since you have multiple consecutive equations,
2. Use a `\makebox` to obtain an alignment of the `conditions`.

[image]

### Notes:

- It is only necessary to apply the `\MakeBox` macro on one of the cases.
- I used the `mathtools` package as that incorporates some fixes on `amsmath` even though it doesn't make a difference in this particular case.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand*{\WidestExpression}{\frac{\alpha m}{1 - m} \left( \theta s - \theta r \right) Se^{\frac{1}{m}} [1 - Se^{\frac{1}{m}} ]^m}
\newcommand*{\MakeBox}[1]{\makebox[\widthof{$\WidestExpression$}][l]{$#1$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \theta &= \begin{cases}
  \theta r + Se \left( \theta s - \theta r \right)  & Hp < 0 \\
   \MakeBox{\theta s}                               & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
 Se &=  \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{[1 + |\alpha Hp|^n]^m}                   & Hp < 0 \\
  \MakeBox{1}                                       & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
 C_m &= \begin{cases}
  \WidestExpression                                 & Hp < 0 \\
  0                                                 & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases} \\
 K_r &= \begin{cases}
  Se^ l [1-[1- Se^{\frac{1}{m}}]^m] ^2              & Hp < 0 \\
  \MakeBox{1}                                       & Hp \geq 0
  \end{cases}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```