# How do I define a piecewise function in latex?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I just saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside) but it doesn't answer mine. How do I define a function something like

f(x) = { bla bla if x<0 
          bla bla if x>0

The [above question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside) doesn't answer how to write f(x) before the bracket

Please help.

Comment: If you want `f(x)=` before the bracket, then just write `f(x)=` before the `\begin{cases}` (and after the `$` or `\[`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

LaTeX is very flexible. Although it is not WYSIWYG you can write it in a very logical way. So if you want to have to have f(x) precede your cases, just write it that way. Here with the example of the linked question.

[image: cases]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
          0 & x\leq 0 \\
          \frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
          0 & 100\leq x 
       \end{cases}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarko C&P from the linked post in OP. I should have looked at it ;) But I'm too lazy to change for now.

Comment: Say, instead of a left curly brace is it possible to define a left bracket i.e, "[" for this command

Comment: @Cristofer That's not built into LaTeX. While you can cheat using `\left[\begin{array}{ll}…\end{array}\right.` it's better to ask a new question with your specific requirements.

Answer (score 5):

TeX is very flexible. Although it is not WYSIWYG you can write it in a very logical way. So if you want to have to have f(x) precede your cases, just write it that way.

```
$$
  f(x) = \cases{        0       & $x\le 0$ \cr
                 100-x\over 100 & $0\le x\le 100$ \cr
                        0       & $100\le x$ }
$$
\bye
```

Comment: Maybe someone didn't understand the joke :-)