# How to write the following mathematical expression in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

How to write  the following mathematical expression in LaTeX?
[image]

Comment: What is your particular doubt? Do you know the basics of (La)TeX? What have you done so far? Could you add some minimal base code to help the other users start from something rather that start with a plain blank file.

Comment: The braced part can be done with `cases` from `amsmath`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside/32142#32142

Answer (score 3):

There are errors in the original, which I have tried to correct.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\[
f^+_A \tilde{\circ} g_A^+ \colon S \longrightarrow P(U), x \longmapsto
\begin{cases}
\bigcup_{x=pq} \left\{f_A^+(p) \cap g_A^+(q)\right\}, & \text{ if \(\exists p,q \in S\) such that \(x=pq\)},
\emptyset, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```