# How to write multiple equations

Tags: math-mode

I would like to make a dual and triple equation by using the following notation:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside/32142#32142

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't give me what I need `$u_i=$ $\[ \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & if OR_i \leq r \\ 0 & if if not\\ \end{array} \right. \]`

Comment: Sir @Mico, you mark my question as had an answer, but it did not give me my need

Comment: `\[ .. \]` starts math mode, don't put it inside `$ ... $`, which also starts math mode. It would likely be better to use the `cases` environment though. And you'll want to use `\text{if }` and `\text{if not}`. For example `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} \[ u_i= \begin{cases}     1 & \text{if } OR_i \leq r \\     0 & \text{if not}  \end{cases} \] \end{document}`