# Equation in Latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, cases

I am new in the latex. I am trying to write an equation in the latex. I have searched a lot of question regarding equations and tried all possible solutions but I m not getting what I want. I also used different tools but still not getting my equation. Kindly help me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe you can get some inspirations in [this tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#The_cases_environment) or [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/240868/164314).

Comment: Use the `cases` environment.  See [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32140/how-to-write-a-function-piecewise-with-bracket-outside).

Comment: Or dcases from mathtools. I guess that the main problem is that no one really wants to type up things from a screen shot. So you may get an answer more quickly if you post what you have tried in such a way that one could just copy and paste these lengthy texts.

Comment: Your definitions are weird. I think the condition of speed on the first line is redundant or non required, because your 3rd line says that the value is 1 regardless of the speed condition. Check the cases environment, and you might need some alignment tips. How do you want to label it? A single number for the whole equation? A number plus a letter per branch? Finally, check how to put regular text within an equation. It avoids having the if condition typeset as the product of i*f.

Comment: @marmot yes I agree with you that I have to show my code but that code doesn't give a sense.  I know how to add other expressions but the problem is am not getting how to start it. Next time I will be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with phollox that logically this does not make too much sense, nor do I now if SVP is a product of 3 variables or some expression. Nevertheless, the following my give you a start.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\[
 AD=\begin{dcases}
 1 & \text{if}~\left(\left(\frac{AC}{4G}+\frac{\text{Noise}}{\si{400\decibel}}\right)\right)
 \ge\text{Accident
 threshold}\wedge\left(\text{Speed}\ge\si{24\kilo\meter\per\hour}\right)
 \\
 1 & \text{if}~\left(\left(\frac{AC}{4G}+\frac{\text{Noise}}{\si{400\decibel}}
 +\frac{SVP}{2.06}\right)\right)
 \ge\text{Low speed threshold}\\
 1 & \text{if}~\left(\left(\frac{AC}{4G}+\frac{\text{Noise}}{\si{400\decibel}}
 \right)\right)
 \ge\text{Accident threshold}\\
 0 &\text{otherwise}
 \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a perfect answer that helps me a lot.