# How to number the parts of a piece wise function equation separately?

Tags: math-mode

A [simple piece-wise function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32142/67392):

```
\[ \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      \frac{100-x}{100} & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
      0 & 100\leq x 
   \end{cases}
\]
```

It will build as equation (1).

I want it to build as (1a) and (1b).

How to do this? Why is this inadvisable?

Comment: (1) please always post full but minimal examples (makes it a lot easier for others to help) (2) se the empheq package, as far as I remember this is an example in the package manual

Comment: May be helpful: [Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the extension `cases`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{numcases}{f(x) = }
0 & if $x\leq 0$ \\
\frac{100-x}{100} & if $0\leq x\leq 100$ \\
0 & if $100\leq x$ 
\end{numcases}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Really odd to have those `$` in the middle of the equation.

Comment: Yes. In `numcases`, the first column is in math mode and the second column is in text mode.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways: with the `subnumcases` environment from `cases`, and with `alignat` and package `empheq`. Note that in the latter case, needless to load `amsmath`: the package loads `mathtools`, which loads amsmath.  I also give two variant layouts, one with the formulæ in each case vertically centred w.r.t. each other (uses `eqparbox`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M]{\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
 \begin{empheq}[left={f(x) = \empheqlbrace\,}]{alignat = 2}
     & \eqmathbox{0} &\qquad & x\leq 0 \\
      &\eqmathbox{\frac{100-x}{100}} & & 0\leq x\leq 100 \\
      &\eqmathbox{0 }& &100\leq x
   \end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\bigskip

 \begin{subnumcases}{f(x) =}
  0 & $ x\leq 0 $ \\
  \frac{100-x}{100} & $ 0\leq x\leq 100 $ \\
  0 & $ 100\leq x $
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]